# How to recover a crashed game in Vulture's

Tags: nethack, technical-issues, slashem

I was playing SLASH'em with the Vulture's GUI, on Mac OSX.  The applicatiion crashed, and now when I try to start, I get a popup telling me that I have a game already with that name, and asking if I want to destroy it.  Selecting "no" quits Vulture's.  Does this mean that the crashed game is recoverable, and if so, how do I go about doing so?

Comment: Have you tried running SLASH'em normally without the GUI, and then loading the save that way? If that works, it may fix things to just save again in the normal game and then try loading through the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar situation with normal nethack where there was a file left suggesting a game was in progress, but not enough to actually continue.

I had to manually delete the file to allow a new game to start. (I think it was a file with my username, but I don't recall for sure.)